# Is it possible to read event logs on-chain?

Tags: solidity, events, logs

I'm integrating with a 3rd party contract, and I need a memory variable that they emit. Is it possible to read logs on-chain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot: the Log and its event data is not accessible from within contracts, not even from the contract that created them ([see the docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#events)).